# Rating Bar with 10 stars in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

My requirement is to open a dialog that allows users to rate content and it has 10 stars in the dialog. I tried different things but it didn't work. Below is my `rating_dialog.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/dialog_rating_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_15"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_30"
            android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/colorHint"
            android:progressTint="@color/color_orange"
            android:secondaryProgressTint="@color/color_orange"
            android:numStars="10"
            android:scaleX="1.8"
            android:scaleY="1.8" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It shows only 9 stars and the Rating Bar layout is also not proper. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: Pls, check my answer

Answer (score 4):

**You can try like this. Working for me  opened with bottom  [image]**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="62dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:text="@string/str_rate_this"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />

        <RatingBar
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Indicator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:numStars="10"
                android:rating="5"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:isIndicator="false"
android:scaleX=".9"
            android:scaleY=".9"
                android:stepSize="1" />

        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_background"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:text="Rate now" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks bro!!! It worked but can you provide start and end margin to Rating Bar precisely as you want? Or will that damage your layout

Comment: I now noticed that it shows only 9 stars in my rating dialog. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is my updated xml [link](https://pastebin.com/Cat8Xe6R) and when a rating image is tapped I show this by using a dialog object.

Comment: This is your updated xml [link](https://pastebin.com/m1Q7zbNf). and this is result screen [link](https://nimb.ws/UWVFac).check this

Answer (score 1):

You have given `android:layout_width="300dp"` to your root `LinearLayout` and that is a reason why it is not showing 10th star.

To make it work you need to give it `match_parent` or `wrap_content` based on your requirement

Answer (score 0):

[image]Try this,

```
   <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/dialog_rating_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_15"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_30"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_30"
        android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/colorHint"
        android:progressTint="@color/color_orange"
        android:secondaryProgressTint="@color/color_orange"
        android:numStars="10"
        android:scaleX="1.8"
        android:scaleY="1.2" />
```

Just to fit the star I  have reduced the scaleY to 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

I once used this [library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/7874),you can choose the amount of stars you want